# SSH Script with encrypted passwords

Tags: encryption, ssh, expect

I have the following script to SSH into a server with wheel user. It is a test script that I want to use in many servers and applications. But rather than giving the passwords as plain text inside the script I want it to be hidden or encrypted and then decrypted when the script is run.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 2

set ip 78.47.1xx.xx
set port 22
set rootpwd adgajfgjagf
set wuser winner
set wpwd winner#@!


spawn ssh -l $wuser $ip -p $port
            expect -re "connecting (yes/no)?" {
            send -- "yes\r"
            }
            expect -nocase -re "password:" {
            send "$wpwd\r"
           }

        expect "# " {
        send  -- "su - root\r"
            expect "Password: "
            send -- "$rootpwd\r"
            interact
        } ## Heading ##
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use ssh key login instead?

For every machine you want to be able to connect, you have to ask for their public ssh-key and add them to autorized_keys. Then when connectig via ssh, those machines do not need to enter a password.

source: http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/mirrors/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO-4.html

Comment: Yeah.. I know I can do that but I need for some other purpose where I am not privileged to use ssh keys.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've had to make do with obfuscation ([yencode](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/base64/yencode.html)) and file permissions.